# Magento Image File Uploader Error : $_FILES array is empty

Tags: php, magento, admin, image-uploading, image-upload

I am new in magento,

I had configured one theme in my magento store,

Followed these configuration steps : [configuration](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/quick-start-guide/magento-themes/v1-0/index_en.html)

Everything works fine, but when i am trying to upload an IMAGE to a product from 
`admin->manage product`

i am facing below error :

[image]

I had tried to clear all the flush from `CACHE MANAGEMENT`.

but its negative. even i tried to set  `upload_tmp_dir`

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of reasons which might cause this issue.
check for followings

- `upload_max_filesize` should be large
- Privileges of your media folder
- Enough space either in PHP tmp catalog or media catalog
- check your server for file upload enabled (might be you have `file_uploads=Off`)

check the link for more options [What to Check if You Cannot Upload Magento Images](https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/tipstricks/what-to-check-if-you-cannot-upload-magento-images/)